# How to properly covert timestamp to ISO 8601 in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm getting the timestamp from http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

So for `2016/1/1 @ 1:1:1` the timestamp should be `1451610061` which is equivalent to `2016-01-01T01:01:01+00:00` in `ISO 8601` (from the site), but when I run the code below I would get the output of `2016-01-01T02:01:01+01:00` instead. Am I missing something?

```
$ts = 1451610061;
echo date('c', $ts);
```

Comment: According to [this](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) site, `1451610061` results in `Fri, 01 Jan 2016 01:01:01 GMT` so its a server issue. Perhaps add a `timezone` to the `datetime`.

Comment: Works fine here too https://eval.in/725142 too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly a timezone issue, as can be seen from "+00:00" vs "+01:00".

You can also verify this by setting the default timezone before with [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
```

> 2016-01-01T01:01:01+00:00

See [eval.in - UTC](https://eval.in/725371)

vs

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
```

> 2016-01-01T02:01:01+01:00

See [eval.in - Berlin](https://eval.in/725366)

---

You can also find out about your local timezone with [`date_default_timezone_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

[eval.in - local timezone](https://eval.in/725406)

> UTC

Which also explains why `http://eval.in` shows the expected output.

---

Of course, you can set the timezone on a `DateTime` object individually

```
$ts = 1451610061;
$dt = new DateTime("@$ts");

$utc = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$dt->setTimezone($utc);
echo "UTC=", $dt->format('c'), "\n";

$berlin = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
$dt->setTimezone($berlin);
echo "Berlin=", $dt->format('c'), "\n";
```

This will show

> UTC=2016-01-01T01:01:01+00:00
>   Berlin=2016-01-01T02:01:01+01:00

[eval.in - setTimezone](https://eval.in/725388)

---

To finally answer your question: there's nothing wrong with your code. `2016-01-01T02:01:01+01:00` is a perfectly valid representation of this timestamp according to [ISO 8601 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).